# Unable to scrape table from new web page while performing webdriver wait...timeout error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to increase a date range of a table that gets generated from a different web page than the one where I set the parameters (that is how it is set up and there is nothing I can do to change that), then scrape it to a text or csv file. However, I always receive this timeout error by the time this date range even gets up to greater than 10 days.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.001
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.122)
```

I eventually want this dataset to be greater than 20 years worth of data, but that will take forever if I can only download days at a time!!! So I've been trying to use an explicit wait from webdriver, and I have been trying to use `--headless`, but I have no idea if I am using any of these features correctly.

What I can present is the very beginning of my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os
import html5lib
import time


#Load webpage faster
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```

...and the following code when I try to have my code pay attention from one web page to another. The `'/html/body/p[2]/text()[2]'` xpath is the very last item on the webpage I would like to load completely.

```
#Click Run Button From First Webpage
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Run').click()
#time.sleep(2)
driver.implicitly_wait(2) 

#Scrape Second Web Page
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/p[2]/text()[2]')))
df_url = driver.current_url
```

I've even tried `By.CLASS_NAME = 'info'` for good measure.

So my questions for this are the following...how can I be able to use selenium to download a bigger dataset? In particular, how can I best use explicit waits from webdriver or headless for what I am trying to deal with right now (building my dataset bit by bit using data from every 10-15 days)? Any assistance is truly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the issue completely.  Is the webpage taking too long to download, or is Selenium not processing its content timely?

Comment: does your data set appears after scrolling down to more data or you need to navigate to next page?

Comment: Is it possible to share the website link, so that I can try it out? I will not be able to reproduce the problem otherwise. If not, then I suggest that you remove the headless option to be see what is happening in the browser. Maybe that will give you some hints as to what needs to be done.

Comment: S.D. and Manish, so what is happening is my new webpage IS taking too long to download and the data set is scrolling down to more data.

agastya, unfortunately I cannot provide what website I use, but what I can do is provide the entire code with an aliased website.